# Laravel/Bouncer check ownership at the gate

Tags: laravel

I am new to bouncer, I would like to verify ownership using middleware. The ownedVia closure does run, but even if I force it to return false the Report model is returned when I request the route. What am I missing?

**AppServiceProvider@boot**

```php
Bouncer::ownedVia(Report::class, function ($report, $user) {
    Log::info('Closure ran!');
    return $report->hub->user_id === $user->id;
});
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('report/{report}', 'ReportController@get')->middleware('can:view-report,report');
```

**ReportController**

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Report::class);
}

public function get(Report $report)
{
    return new ReportResource($report);
}
```

**UserService**

```php
Bouncer::allow($user)->toOwn(Report::class);
```

**User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRolesAndAbilities;
```

Comment: BTW (not that it matters here) you should be checking for the `view` ability, not `view-report`.

Comment: view-report is an ability I created with bouncer

Comment: My point is, you shouldn't include the name of the model in your ability names. The ability you created with Bouncer should be just `view`, and not `view-report`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user doesn't have a different ability that is allowing that?

Try this instead:

1. Remove the middleware from the route.
2. Remove the call to `authorizeResource` in the constructor.
3. Then, at the top of your `get` method, add this:

   ```php
   dd(\Gate::authorize('view', $report));
   ```

This [should log the actual ability](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/c2a4eb33266a36e381e09f8a3556f056e8ea996d/src/Guard.php#L210) that allowed the action.

Comment: A verbose response: https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/438#issuecomment-492899463